# Running a local website without localhost

Tags: server, webserver, localhost, hosts

I'm developing some frontend Javascript code for the first time on Ubuntu.
I have the code (written over the last year by others)  for the site installed and ready to run.

But on this Ubuntu machine I have to access it as http://meso.dev.cc:9000 **not** localhost:9000

Do I have to edit a host file? If so what should I place in that file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, exactly: add the following line to `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 meso.dev.cc
```

and your address will work.

Comment: do I need to port number as well ?

Comment: No, port numbers do not go in `/etc/hosts`. Instead, you put them in the URL, as you did in the question.